# Table with multiple inner tables and Fixed Header Table with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have been working with a table which has 3 inner tables. and the third table being wider in width and has horizontal scroll.

I have been trying to fix the header for each table and trust me I tried all the solutions but none of the solution over the internet has the same thing as I do (or may be I couldn't find one)

I tried various plugins floathead and fixedheadertable but the horizontal thing breaks it.

I have my jsfiddle example up can anyone show me the way maybe

http://jsfiddle.net/warlockdn/qyrjvnvv/2/

I am open to restructure the table but not sure what way to take ?

This is the basic structure

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Latest</td>
            <td>Oil Majors</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table></table>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if you see the jsfiddle example there is one master table and within that table there are 3 tables with <thead>. The third table which is under Oil Majors has a horizontal scroll. What I want to do it have the head fixed on scroll for Vessel, Latest and Oil Majors. Basically all the cells in green to fix on scroll. http://fiddle.jshell.net/warlockdn/qyrjvnvv/2/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery with scroll event to make this. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($("thead"),function(){
        $(this).css({position:'relative'})
    })

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("thead").css({top:$(window).scrollTop()})
    })
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uj313udL/

**UPDATE**
I've modified a lot of your code. I've added width on all headers. It works fine with Firefox and Chrome. Please try:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nzdhs4wq/

Comment: thank you for helping out. But not sure is it working on your side ? Coz, I don't see the head for the table being fixed on the top ? thanks again.

Comment: it's strange.work fine for me. in the fiddle, the head is lock and the first row show bellow the header. when you scroll the contents row scroll under head. it's not what you want?

Comment: Not sure. M halfway till middle of the box the header doesn't stick on my side. yea I want the thing the same you wrote sadly i don't see that working on my side.

Update :- works on firefox. Not chrome.

Comment: What is your browser?

Comment: Using chrome. and firefox. Chrome doesn't seem to work. But in firefox its working properly.

Comment: In chrome, you can't make "postition:relative" in a table element (row or col). If you want make this, you must change the way you do. div menu or single table just for menu

Comment: oops so close to an answer not stuck. is there a way around without making a div for top head ?

Comment: OK, now working with all browser. please see my update

Comment: Thank you for your effort. but did you see the fullscreen demo of your code. 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/nzdhs4wq/show/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93475/discussion-between-deepankar-and-p-frank).

Answer (score 1):

So,

I got the table to work as I needed with the help from @Frank.

Used the code he gave. Since the table won't take position relative to row or column. I added a div inside each  under  and changed the jquery code to catch the class.

```
$.each($(".stick_top"),function(){
    $(this).css({position:'relative'})
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    $(".stick_top").css({top:$(window).scrollTop()})
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/warlockdn/uj313udL/8/

It works fine now. Thank you Frank.

Comment: one small question. so my table in the original page is way down at the bottom. so the top is calculated from the top of the window scroll. is it possible to trigger it once I am inside the container where the table is being displayed ?

Comment: oops so silly of me. I did it. work pressure makes it confusing you know when I need it the most.